# The Java LinkedHashSet uses a doubly-linked list. Can it also be iterated backwards?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, iteration, hashset

Oracle-Documentation says following about LinkedHashSet: "Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries."

The iterator you can get is in insertion order. Iteration in reverse-insertion order would also be technicially feasable thought, as it's a **doubly**-linked.

Can such a reverse-Iterator be created (or even a ListIterator which does both)?

Comment: No. Just a regular forward-going iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet` doesn't expose any API to iterate over it backwards. Although this would have a really bad performance impact, you could copy the `LinkedHashSet` to a `List` (retaining its order) and then iterate backwards on it:

```java
LinkedHashSet<SomeClass> myLinkedHashSet = ...;
List<SomeClass> myList = new ArrayList<>(myLinkedHashSet); // Order is retained
ListIterator<SomeClass> myIter = myList.listIterator(myList.size());
while (myIter.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(myIter.previous());
}
```

Comment: Yea I'm definetly not gonna do that. But: Why is it doubly-linked then? Because elsewise the linkedList couln't be fixed when elements are removed?

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedHashMap iterator only supports going forward. You can read its implementation in [OpenJDK in the github mirror](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9d764ee48ee7c2e7be7a25aee2ed7bed2fcd2000/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#L740). It's not like the implementation privately implemented `ListIterator` and secretly supported iterating backwards.

The hash table lookup gives you a pointer to an entry that's somewhere in the list.  To remove it, you need a reference to the previous list entry. That's why LinkedHashMap needs to use a doubly linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the second paragraph, this clarifies my comment on the top answer.

Comment: Your answer refers to `LinkedHashMap` when the original question was `LinkedHashSet`.  All your points are pretty much still applicable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 21, `LinkedHashSet` has the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#reversed()) method, which returns a reversed view of the set.

An iterator can be retrieved from this reversed view, same as for any collection:

```java
Iterator<Object> iterator = myLinkedHashSet.reversed().iterator();
```

Additionally, as with any `Iterable`, there are various ways to iterate over this reversed view, including the [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) method:

```java
myLinkedHashSet.reversed().forEach(element -> {
  // Do something with the element
});
```